# How do you think through and predict the output of a threading question like this?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm prepping for the SCJP, and multithreading has been my shakiest area, mostly because I don't know how to look at multithreading code and walk through it. So far my approach has been to write down in English what might be happening in each thread and testing a few cases with threads randomly intersecting each other, which is a really hit-and-miss and time-consuming approach. So I'd like to see how a pro would go about it. Would you be willing to read the code below (it's the latest question that's giving me trouble) and write down what goes through your head (code-related stuff only, please :) as you work out the possible outputs? The choices that come with the question are at the end. What I'm looking for isn't the solution, which I have, but how one arrives at the solution efficiently on the exam.

And yeah, I know this question doesn't have a precise answer, etc etc. Accepted vote goes to the answer that's clearest and easiest to emulate, okay :)

Thanks everyone!

Question: Which of these answers are possible outputs?

```
public class Threads1 {

    int x = 0;

    class Runner implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            int current = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                current = x;
                System.out.print(current + ", ");
                x = current + 2;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Threads1().go();
    }

    public void go() {
        Runnable r1 = new Runner();
        new Thread(r1).start();
        new Thread(r1).start();
    }
}
```

Choices (choose all that apply):

A. 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 6,

B. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4,

C. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

D. 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14,

E. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

Comment: So what's the answer Anita?  I'd like to see your answer before I give you my way of thinking of the problem.

Comment: Visualization is the key, make your own diagramming technique, enough to show what is going on concurrently and what resources are shared between each thread.

Comment: I didn't give the answer because that'd be too easy :) Seriously though, once I know the answer, I can explain why it's right, but it's figuring out what it is in the first place that I need to do and can't do yet.

Comment: The real answer to this question is that this is horrible, horrible multithreaded coding and anybody producing code like this in a production environment should not only be immediately fired, but in fact banned from ever programming again.

Comment: @kyoryu Imagine you got some legacy code to refactor, would you just tell your boss "nah, that's some god ugly piece of code, don't wanna fix it. let me check SO instead!11". The SCJP threading exercises aren't that bad, in fact you can learn pretty much out of it.

Comment: @kyoryu Like the old math question about trains hurtling toward each other at different speeds and you have to figure out when they pass each other, the point of the question and the test is **not** to show production code.  Its to show you have a strong grasp of the concepts *and* the ability to apply them.  Untangling this output is a good way to demonstrate that.

Comment: No, I'd fix the code.  I'm pretty sure the answer is A, C here, and the unlocked gap between reading the current value of x and modifying it is the reason.  And yes, I understand the point of the exercise.  But if people get used to seeing multithreading code like this, my fear would be that they would think that this is an appropriate way to write it, and use the 'tricks' they found in code like this.  If junior devs are looking at bad code as an exercise, I really want them to be aware that it's bad code up front.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**A and C**  (assuming the question is *Which of these answers are possible outputs?*)

The hard part, of course, isn't when you find a possible solution.  But rather, its to look hard at the ones that you think are **not** possible and try to convinced yourself that you've got a solid reason why its not possible **and** that you've eliminated all the ways to get around your reason.

> So far my approach has been to write down in English what might be happening in each thread ...

You need to figure out which thread printed each number.  Below is the most efficient,  succinctness format I could think of represent that and make it easy to crossout/erase/write-over as you work through possibilities. Realize:

- Once you find an possible answer **move on**.  It doesn't matter if it isn't likely in the real world or that there may be other possible (or impossible) combinations.  As long as you found 1 possibility, that's all you need to **move on**.
- Try the simplest approach first, e.g. assume T1 for each number until you hit a number that couldn't be T1, so you fill in T2, and so on..  Hopefully, you get to the end with no contradiction (or contradictions that are easy to resolve).  Once you've found a possible combination, move on.
- Feel free to skip around to *eliminate* the possible ones quickly so you can focus on the likely impossible ones.

Here is the final edit of my scratch-paper/worksheet (appended with my mental annotations):

```
A. 0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 8, 10, 6,
   1  1  1  2  2  2   2  1     <- possible threads that produced this output - possible solution

B. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4,
   1  2  2  2  2   ?  1        <- to print second '2', T1 interrupted between L10/L11; 4 passes of T2 used up

C. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
   1  1  1  1  2   2   2   2   <- possible solution - simplest solution (T2 waits until T1 is completely done) - doesn't matter that it isn't likely, just that is possible

D. 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 14,
   1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2  1  2   ?    <- threads used up

E. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,
   1  1  1  1  2   2   2   2  ?   <- threads used up
```

Note:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

> - Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables and for most primitive variables (all types except long and double).
> - ...
>
> Atomic actions cannot be interleaved, so they can be used without fear of thread interference.

Comment: @BertF can we think in way like this: No matter of the execution of the threads, there must be most 8 numbers printed, so D and E can't be produced by this example and then to use your thoughts for A,B and C?

Comment: Sounds right to me @Xelian - your approach would eliminate D and E quickly.

Answer (score 5):

My approach to multi-threaded problems is to break up the code that the thread will run and then determine how many threads will run that code and if the access any variables that other threads could potentially use.

In the example, there are 3 threads.  The `main` thread calls `new Threads1().go();`, creates `r1`, and starts 2 more threads, `new Thread(r1).start();` and `new Thread(r1).start();`.  Now that we know how many threads we can track what they are going to do.

The `main` thread is going to die after it returns from `go()`.

The other 2 threads are each going to enter the `run()` method of the `Runner` object, `r1`.  Now what we also know is that each thread will execute `run()`.  So lets look at what `run()` does.  It has a `for` loop that prints output each time it executes the loop.  Therefore the call to `run()` will print `4` times.  So 2 threads each thread will print `4` times.  Therefore the output cannot have any more than `8` numbers.

Regarding what those digits will be is not really going to be possible since the `Runner` instance will be the same for each thread the `x` variable can change based on the other thread that is also calling `run()`.  Therefore all you need to determine is, is the sequence of digits possible?  The answer to that question is 'yes' for A and C.  This is due to the fact that you have no idea when each thread will be preempted by the other and since during the loop there is a local copy being made, you could get some very unique orderings.

As mentioned below by SB the, option B even though it has 8 outputs it is not possible.  Try and come up with a thread sequence to create that output.

Comment: Oh wow.  That is a good call.  My bad.  I will correct that.  Great catch.

Comment: the answer could be A, B, or even C depending on what priority each thread has and when each instruction is executed. My best guess would be to answer A as it is the only answer that display some repeating numbers interlaced, meaning that both thread are being executed in parallel. But any of the first 3 could be justified.

Comment: @Yanick - No, I thought that at first also but B is not possible.  You cannot have 6 increasing numbers and then 2 increasing because that would mean that 1 thread wrote at least 5 times.

Comment: @linuxuser27, yea, I tried to edit my comment, but couldn't. B is not valid, because when 2 is echo'ed from the second thread, the next number should be greater or equal to 12 from the first thread

Comment: @Yanick - It is a classic example that even after years of doing multi-threaded work you can still look at 'potential' output and make a mistake.  We are in good company I assume :)

Comment: @linuxuser27, well, this is a classic tail of one doing more than one thing at a time and not paying closer attention to the question :) Error is human. If I was doing that test, I would have most probably gone back to the question and corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a lot more deceptive than it looks -- I'm liking it the more I think about it.  I started my answer talking about how I look at thread programs -- I analyze the synchronization points and the I/O calls.  But this has none except for the println which has no internal synchronization.  So we are left with random timing (see [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)).  This combined with no guaranteed way to synchronize the values of `x` between the threads means that it will be random.

However, if we look at the answers, we can see that some of the answers cannot occur.  For example, as @linuxuser27 pointed out, each thread prints out 4 numbers only which removes answers will more numbers printed.  Another example of an improper answer would be if any of the answers had a value larger than 14 since the first thread can go 0,2,4,6 and the 2nd could take it to 8,10,12,14 but no higher.

Since each of the threads must print a number 4 times and numbers printed by *each thread* must be at least 2+ the previous number the thread printed, some of the patterns cannot be generated.  I won't give my answer but is is not 'all of the above' and it is not A, B, and C.

Comment: `each of the numbers must be at least 2+ the previous number they printed` I thought so too, and I was wrong :(

Comment: If t2 advances more than t1, t2's `current` will be larger than t1's `current`, so when t1 takes back the CPU from t2, x will assume t1's lower `current`, and that lower `current` will be printed after the higher one. So the output can still go down.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  What I meant is that t1's number always goes up by at least 2 from what t1 printed previously and t2's number as well.