# How to predict thread id in output?

Tags: java, multithreading

Following is code from OCJP exam

```
class Test implements Runnable{

  synchronized void hit(long n) {
     for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        System.out.print(n + "-" + i + " ");
  }

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   
     new Thread(new Test()).start();
     new Thread(new Test()).start();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
     hit(Thread.currentThread().getId());
  }
}
```

> Answer: 8-1 7-1 7-2 8-2 and
>
> 8-1 8-2 7-1 7-2

How this output is predicted?

Answer (score 8):

You can't predict it. The threads are running in parallel and the output order will be effectively random between the threads although the order will be deterministic on each individual thread.

The synchronized on hit() is also doing nothing as each thread has its own Test object so is only synchronizing with itself.

In other words 8-2 will always follow 8-1. 7-2 will always follow 7-1, but the order of all the 7s is completely separate from the order of all the 8s. This means that given a set of possible outputs you can say that some are impossible and some are possible, you cannot predict what actual output will be produced though.

You should also read this question and the answers to it, very informative on this subject:

[How do you think through and predict the output of a threading question like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800146/how-do-you-think-through-and-predict-the-output-of-a-threading-question-like-thi?rq=1)

Comment: This question is from ocjp dumbs.So what if such a question asked in ocjp exam.OR such type of question will never there?

Comment: You may right because on pc output is showing 8-1 8-2 9-1 9-2

Comment: If the question is asked then the answer is that you can't predict it beyond the constraints I put in my answer. It's unlikely to be asked like that though as it would probably qualify as a trick question.

Comment: The question could be "indicate a possible outcome". OP's question contains one *impossible* and one *possible* outcome. That would be a fair question then.

Comment: If it is a multiple choice question, you need to separate the possible  outputs form the impossible: For example, this would be impossible: `8-2 7-1 7-2 8-1` or `8-1 9-2 10-1 10-2`

Answer (score 1):

You can't predict it, but you can set Thread's name yourself with some kind of counter (if that means anything to you).

```
Thread myThread = new Test();
myThread.setName(counter++);
```